# Deploy two VSTS repositories to one Azure web app

Tags: node.js, git, azure, azure-web-app-service

Let's say I have an Azure App Service web app at `foo.azurewebsites.net`. The code for the web app (a simple Node.js server and React frontend) is hosted on VSTS, and a custom deployment script is configured build and deploy the web app every time code is pushed to the repository's `master` branch. In other words, the standard web app configuration.

Now, all of my API code (just a Node.js server) is in another repository on VSTS. I'd like to be able to do the following:

1. Have all requests to `foo.azurewebsites.net/api` be handled by the API server (an implication of this, which I would nonetheless like to state explicitly, is that the server can ask the browser to set cookies that the web app can then read, and vice versa).
2. Set up similar continuous deployment for the API server, such that it gets redeployed whenever there are code changes in the API repo.
3. Be able to maintain the web app and API repositories completely separately.

This seems like a fairly standard scenario...is there an accepted solution? I came across [this](https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/automatic-deployment-of-multiple-repositories-to-azure), but it seems like a pretty hacky way to do it, not to mention the fact that I have no idea what the correct URL is for the web hook for VSTS and can't seem to find any information on it. Also, that example doesn't cover how to deal with point (1) above.

#### EDIT: Additional clarification

Note that the accepted answer on [this question](http://Note%20that%20(this)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44709776/deploy-to-azure-web-app-from-multiple-repositories]) is not what I'm looking for. It describes how to pull from a second repository at deployment time, but not how to have that second repository *trigger* deployments, or how to handle the fact that the the second repository is its own server. Additionally, it introduces a dependency between the two repositories, since the `deploy.cmd` is presumably under source control in the first repository.

#### EDIT: Virtual Directories

Thanks to @CtrlDot for pointing out that Virtual Directories are the way to solve (1). Still seeking guidance on (2) and (3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the concept you are referring to is called [Virtual Directories](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/)

I'm not sure which VSTS task you are using to deploy, but based on the article provided, you should be to configure it to target only the virtual directory you want to deploy to.

**EDIT**

Sorry for not being more clear.  The [AzureRmWebAppDeployment](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/AzureRmWebAppDeployment) task has a parameter for virtual application name.  You would simply set that in your deployment pipeline for the API project (/api) and for the main project (leave it blank)

Comment: Thanks, it looks like Virtual Directories are the right way to go for making (1) work. But what about setting up continuous deployment from both repositories? All of the related questions I've seen have to do with putting the API and web app in multiple projects in a single Visual Studio solution. This is not an option for me, unfortunately.

Comment: Ah okay. I have not been using a custom build process on the VSTS side; I've just been letting Azure handle the source control integration. I will look into it.